# Payment Plugin is not displaying on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have a plugin is working fine with Prestashop 1.6 but since Prestashop made major changes in the latest version 1.7 the plugin stopped working.

I have followed the link which they provided but still the plugin is not working:
    http://build.prestashop.com/news/starter-theme-news-3/

The plugin is working perfect in the backend I have installed it, But the problem is not showing up on the checkout process, I have enabled **dev mode** to see if there is any error but nothing, I have checked also the error logs there is nothing.

Here is the code:

Payroll.php and payment.tpl:

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach the link of the code:  https://pastebin.com/79eSEa3t

Comment: Anyone can help here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the install you register the module in payment:

```
$this->registerHook('payment')
```

Instead of paymentoptions:

```
$this->registerHook('paymentOptions')
```

As used in the ps_wirepayment module.

Comment: try adding use `PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption;` before `if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))` like the official modules